# Tracing drawing with cloned tiles produces different result

Tags: inkscape

While following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/4kdUFjX00iQ?t=114) tracing the circle over the circle with the gradient produces this result:

[image]

The result is different from the result in the tutorial, and I've retraced my steps several times.  Also if I delete the circle that the clones are based on it resets the styling of the clones and makes them all opaque black like this:

[image]

Thoughts on what I could be doing differently to get the same result as the tutorial?  It it the circle the clones are based on is deletedwithout changing the look of the clones.

Comment: Nothing != to white

Comment: I can't replicate the issue in Inkscape 0.92. When I try it, it comes out the same as the tutorial. Deleting the original clone makes no difference either. [screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/K6cSa)

Comment: Interesting.  I'm also running 0.92 on Ubuntu 17.10.  Just to make absolutely sure I started from scratch one more time as a triple check.  I can make a screen cast if need be.

Comment: Bug Report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1750442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circle that is used for the trace should be turned into a path (Select it and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>).  It is not explicitly shown in the video (She probably used the keyboard shortcut).

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see in the screenshot you posted is that all of the clones appear to have the same black color, whereas in the tutorial they seem to be two colors; black and gray.

Since the "color" option is checked in the settings, meaning the clones will take their color from the underlying drawing (the big circle), my guess is that your "big circle" is only one color, i.e. the gradient that the tutorial set for the big circle is **NOT from black in the center to transparent or translucent at the edge**, she set a different color of gray (and 100% opaque) on the outside edge.

So your gradient on the big underlying circle should be from opaque black to opaque gray, and both gradient stops should be 100% opaque.